Is the size_of syntax explained anywhere?
This is how you calculate the size of a data type:
core::mem::size_of::<u32>()

To be honest, the syntax looks super weird. Is this syntax explained anywhere(like in a book)?
Is it normal to provide concrete values to generics in this manner?
I tried the above syntax and it works. Just curious is there's an explanation and more examples for the syntax.

You can read about Turbofish syntax here

Types in Rust do not exist at runtime and cannot be passed around like variables. You can't make a function like this: core::mem::size_of(u32). In some languages something like that does work. Classes in Python (for example) are also objects and can be passed to functions. But in Rust, that is not the case.
